# Is it possible / How to set a delay for jQuery Autocomplete like Google plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using the jQuery plugin [Autocomplete like Google](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/autocomplete/#visibleLimit) and it's working very well. But the AJAX request is triggered on every key press. That means, the string `washington` will cause ten (!) requests. Well, the number of the requests can be reduced by using the option [`minLength`](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/autocomplete/#minLength). But e.g. with `minLength:3` we still send seven requests (beggining by the fourth character).

```
$(function() {
    $("#bar").autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        limit: 5,
        source : [
            function(query, add) {
                fooNumber = $('#foo-number').val();
                $.getJSON("/my/ajax/controller/bar?data[number]=" + query + "&data[foo_name]=" + fooNumber, function(response) {
                    add(response);
                })
        }],  
    });
});
```

**How to prevent the instant requesting the server and make the script only send a new request, when the user hasn't been typing since e.g `300 ms`?**

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful. (Not tested)

```
//global variable
var keyPressed = new Date();
// Call where you're watching for pressed keys.
var updateKeyPressed = function(){
    keyPressed = new Date();
}

$(function() {
    $("#bar").autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        limit: 5,
        appendMethod:'replace',
        closeOnBlur: true,
        source : [
            function(query, add) {
                var currentDate = new Date();
                setInterval(function(){
                    currentDate = new Date();
                    if (currentDate.getTime() > keyPressed.getTime()) {
                        orderApplicationNumber = $('#foo-number').val();
                        $.getJSON("/my/ajax/controller/bar?data[number]=" + query + "&data[foo_name]=" + fooNumber, function(response) {
                            add(response);
                        });
                    }
                }, 300);
            }
        ],
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I corrected the code, so it's executable now (some braces were set incorrect). But now the requests are sent directly after the page is loaded and are sent to the server all the time (like in an infinite loop).

Comment: I set the `currentDate` twice and put the call of the `updateKeyPressed()` to the wrong place. Now I've debugged this -- and it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: It's a really good workaround, but not a solution for me. It also has the side effect, that it prevent autocompletion without typing. Anyway, I will not accept the answer, but give a +1 for it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I missunderstood. You could do some logic with flags and settimeout with the function in source, like (**have not tested it**):

var timer;

```
$("#bar").autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        limit: 5,
        cacheLength: 1,
        source : [
            function(query, add) {

                clearTimeout(timer);

                timer = setTimeout(function(){

                    fooNumber = $('#foo-number').val();
                    $.getJSON("/my/ajax/controller/bar?data[number]=" + query + "&data[foo_name]=" + fooNumber, function(response) {
                        add(response);
                    })

                }, 300)

        }],
    });
```

Or you could switch to jquery ui >

Original answer:

jquery ui autocomplete has a built-in parameter for that, **delay** ([DOCS](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-delay))

From the docs:

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
  delay: 500
});
```

Comment: Thenk you for your answer! It works (with `timer = null;`, in order to avoid the `ReferenceError: timer is not defined`). But it's not, what Im looking for. The timeout means: all the (needless) requests will be sent, just some time later. E.g.: `washington` is still producing 7 requests, that are simply sent a bit later. What I want is reducing of the requests number. The every next requst should be sent. when I stop typing the search word.

Comment: Switching to another autocomplete plugin is not an option currently, so I have to try it with "Autocomplete like Google".